# Where and how to initialize MockWebServer using Junit4 and espresso the latest version

Tags: android, unit-testing, automated-tests, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I went through a couple of posts on stackoverflow and also some blogs that describe what happens with ActivityTestRule and some basics about intregation testing in android.But i am getting confused the more i read.

I have managed to write a test case but the issue I have is that I am not able to decide where to initialize MockWebServer and how to stop the webservice call (original) from happening. I read about Dagger but i do not know if i require it.

My activity class code of what i want to test is as under:

```
Call<List<Repository>> call = null;
call = new RestClient().getApiService().getRepositories();
```

And RestClient looks as under:

```
public class RestClient {
public static String BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/";
private ApiService mApiService;

/**
 * Initializes Retrofit and sets the base point of connection
 */
public RestClient() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    mApiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    }

    /**
     * returns the instance of ApiService needed to make service calls
     * @return
     */
    public ApiService getApiService() {
        return mApiService;
    }
}
```

And ApiService as under:

```
public interface ApiService {
    @GET("repositories")
    Call<List<Repository>> getRepositories();
}
```

My InstrumentationTestClass looks as under:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, false, false);


@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception{
    super.setUp();

    mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
    mockWebServer.start();

    injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());

    RestClient.BASE_URL = mockWebServer.url("/").toString();
}



@Test
@LargeTest
public void testDataLoaded() throws IOException {
    String link = "<https://api.github.com/repositories?since=10>; rel=\"next\"," +
            "<https://api.github.com/repositories?since=0>; rel=\"previous\"";

    String fileName = "repositories.json";
    MockResponse mockResponse = new MockResponse();

    mockResponse.setHeader("Link", link);

    mockWebServer.enqueue(mockResponse
            .setResponseCode(200)
            .setBody(RestClientTestHelper.getStringFromFile(getInstrumentation().getContext(), fileName)));

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    mActivityRule.launchActivity(intent);

    assertNotNull(mockResponse.getBody());
}
```

Some questions and summary of what I have done:

1. How do i prevent the actual network call from taking place and simply make use of mockWebServer to pick records from the json file in the assets folder?
2. I tried initializing mockwebserver in the method beforeActivityLaunched but then tearDown returns with null pointer.
3. I tried initializing mockwebserver in the testFragmentLoaded method and then launched the activity using intent but then it doesnot seem to prevent the web call
4. Is what i am doing the right way? As i am new to automation testing :(

Please assist.

Comment: Hey! Did you get answers to your questions?

Comment: @NarayanAcharya - yes i did, but i am afraid i will need to look at it once more to get back with an answer.

Comment: Great! I tried my hand with Dagger2, RestMock and the likes but the solutions I came up with felt hacky. If you could post your answer, it will be of great help.

Comment: no answer? I'm facing exactly the same problem :(

Comment: @here: Its been a while i worked on this , but i think i used mocks to replicate url calls. So there was this custom injection file that would check if the data passed is "xyz" then it would return values from a constant class file that would have the responses mocked.